# What's the difference between String(value) vs value.toString()

Tags: javascript

Javascript has lot's of "tricks" around types and type conversions so I'm wondering if these 2 methods are the same or if there is some corner case that makes them different?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

They are not completely the same, and actually, [the String constructor called as a function](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.5.1) (your first example), will at the end, call the `toString` method of the object passed, for example:

```
var o = { toString: function () { return "foo"; } };
String(o); // "foo"
```

On the other hand, if an identifier refers to `null` or `undefined`, you can't use the `toString` method, it will give you a **`TypeError` exception**:

```
var value = null;
String(null);     // "null"
value.toString(); // TypeError
```

The `String` constructor called as a function would be roughly equivalent to:

```
value + '';
```

The type conversion rules from *Object*-to-*Primitive* are detailed described on the specification, the [`[[DefaultValue]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6.2.6) internal operation.

Briefly summarized, when converting from *Object*-to-*String*, the following steps are taken:

1. If available, execute the `toString` method.

   - If the `result` is a *primitive*, return `result`, else go to Step 2.
2. If available, execute the `valueOf` method.

   - If the `result` is a *primitive*, return `result`, else go to Step 3.
3. Throw `TypeError`.

Given the above rules, we can make an example of the semantics involved:

```
var o = {
  toString: function () { return "foo"; },
  valueOf:  function () { return "bar"; }
};

String(o); // "foo"

// Make the toString method unavailable:
o.toString = null;

String(o); // "bar"

// Also make the valueOf method unavailable:
o.valueOf = null;

try { 
  String(o); 
} catch (e) {
  alert(e); // TypeError
}
```

If you want to know more about this mechanism I would recommend looking at the [`ToPrimitive`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.1) and the [`ToString`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.8) internal operations.

I also recommend reading this article:

- [Object-to-Primitive Conversions in JavaScript](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/Object-to-Primitive-Conversions-in-JavaScript)

Comment: There is a third "way", if you call this:
`new String(value)`
on any value, it will always return a string object.

Comment: @Herbertusz `new String({toString: null})` throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: With the addition of Symbols `String()` and `+ ''` now have a fairly significant difference. `String(Symbol())` will run, but `Symbol() + ''` will throw an error (and Symbol() will pass a falsey guard, unlike null and undefined, so `x && (x + '')` can now throw).

Comment: Looks like null doesn't have toString and valueOf  methods, but String(null) returns 'null' without throwing error. Special behaviour?

Answer (score 55):

`value.toString()` will cause an error if `value` is null or undefined. `String(value)` should not.

For example:

```
var value = null;
alert(value.toString());
```

will fail because `value == null`.

```
var value = null;
alert(String(value));
```

should display a message reading "null" (or similar), but it will not crash.

Comment: I've never seen a null pointer exception in javascript... where did you see that?

Comment: nice. it would be yet nicer with an example

Comment: @no, @casablanca Fixed. I'm used to Java. @mykhal How does that look?

Comment: It returns a string "null" :)

Answer (score 4):

`String(value)` should have the same result as `value.toString()` in every case, except for values without properties like `null` or `undefined`. `''+value` will produce the same result.

Comment: `''+value` might not produce the same result as `String(value)` if `value` has both a `toString()` method and a `valueOf()` method. For example if `value = {toString(){return "Hello World!"}, valueOf(){return 3}}`, then `String(value)` will be `"Hello World!"` but `''+value` will be `3`. This is because the `+` operator looks for `valueOf` before `toString`, whereas `String(...)` only looks for `toString`.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this with ES6 and found out that for `String()` to look at `valueOf()` inside of the object, the object has to have `toString()` method. If the object does not have `toString()` then console returns `'[object Object]'` regardless of having `valueOf()` or not. So in the the first "step", we always have to have `toString()` regardless, else `String()` method wouldn't look at `valueOf`.

Please check this:

```js
let obj = {
    name:'b',
    age:22,
    valueOf: function(){
        return 'heeee';
    }
}

String(obj); // prints '[object Object]'
```

On the other hand,

```js
let obj = {
    name:'b',
    age:22,
    toString:null,
    valueOf: function(){
        return 'heeee';
    }
}
String(obj); // prints 'heeee'
```

```js
let obj = {
  name: 'b',
  age: 22,
  valueOf: function() {
    return 'heeee';
  }
}

console.log(String(obj));

let obj2 = {
  name: 'b',
  age: 22,
  toString: null,
  valueOf: function() {
    return 'heeee';
  }
}

console.log(String(obj2));
```

Comment: Abstract Operation is working under the cover. If the value to be converted is an Object, ToPrimitive Abstract operation is first called. Which calls toString or valueOf. If the object is capable of being converted into more than 1 primitive types then Hint is passed. In above, object is String Object so toString will be called. If it returns the primitive value, then convert to string (if not already string). If returns a non primitive value then valueOf is called to get primitive value (to convert into string if not string via ToString Abstract method) otherwise Type Error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

**String()** [the *constructor call*] is basically calling the **.toString()**

**.toString()** and **String()** can be called on primitive values(number,boolean,string) and basically will do nothing special:

> true => 'true'
>
> false => 'false'
>
> 17 => '17'
>
> 'hello' => 'hello'

**But** calling these functions on objects is where things gets interesting:

if the object has it's own .toString() function it will be called when ever you need this object to be treated as a string(explicitly/implicitly)

```
let obj = {
           myName:"some object",
           toString:function(){ return this.myName; } 
          }

//implicitly treating this obj as a string
"hello " + obj; //"hello some object"

//OR (explicitly)
"hello " + String(obj) //calling the existent toString function

//OR
"hello " + obj.toString(); //calling toString directly
```

By the way if you want to treat this object as a number it should has a **.valueOf()** function defined in it.

> what if we have both in one object?
>
> if we want to treat this object as a string => use **.toString()**
>
> if we want to treat this object as a number => use **.valueOf()**

what if we only have **.valueOf()** defined?

**.valueOf()** defined inside the object will be called whether we want to handle the object as a string or as a number