# Javascript Object not working with Native javascript methods like match(), replace etc

Tags: javascript, string, object, methods, key

Here is the issue:

I go this Code:

```
var str = {"Acc":10 , "adm_data":"Denied"};
```

When I do something like:

```
console.log(str.Acc.match(/[0-9]+/g)) // To Get the Integer Value from the "Acc" key
```

*Firebug* Screams:

> TypeError: str.Acc.match is not a function
>
> console.log(str.Acc.match(/[0-9]+/g));

See Image:

[image]

I always do something like:

```
var str = "Hello _10";

console.log(str.match(/[0-9]+/g)) // This Works
```

Why is the `Object` thingi not working?

---

> **PLEASE NOTE:**
>
> As mentioned by `@Fabrício Matté.` The issue was that I was trying to
>   pass an `integer` Value to  the `.match` method which does not belong
>   to `integers`. **The solution** was to do what `@kundan Karn`  Suggested. Something like: 
>   `str.Acc.toString().match(/[0-9]+/g)// Converting it first to string then match`. It worked!

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) or didn't happen. Impossible to reproduce with your given example. http://jsfiddle.net/QgdUV/

Comment: Tried your code and it works fine :)
I used nodeJS to test it though

Comment: @Fabricio Matte ... Can you Eplain what You mean?.. @surrender's suggestion worked well but when I try Something like:   `var str = {"Acc":10,"adm_data":"Denied"};`  _Notice the **Raw Integer** value... This gives the Same error back why?

Comment: @UniversalGrasp What I mean is that it is impossible to reproduce the issue with the code in the question. Now that you've shown a number value, the error happens because Numbers do not have inherit `match` which is a string method. Kundan and Kristof's answers should solve the issue.

Comment: **To All [DownVoters] of this Question**: Please Stop downVoting this question... You may be _Experts_ and _GURUs_ but there are guys like me who might face the same issue and this [Question] might be useful...  Thx

Comment: @FabrícioMatté... Instead of downvoting... You'd have Suggestd an Edit to the [Question]

Comment: @UniversalGrasp I'd have suggested an edit, but at the time of asking there was no way to determine the actual issue. I've removed the DV as I see that you've edited the question.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Indeed thanks immensely for you quick scrutiny... That indeed helped me Edit... Lots of Respect to You!..NOTE: We are in the Same Office with UniversalGrasp.. I controll Social Networking Flows

Comment: @Universal Grasp.. Welcome buddy. You should thank _FabrícioMatté_ more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

match function works with string. So convert it to string first

```
str.Acc.toString().match(/[0-9]+/g)
```

Comment: PERFECT!... Exactly it... To All [DownVoters] of this Question: Please Stop downVoting this question... You may be Experts but there are guys like me who might face the same issue and this [Question] might be useful...

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nKHLy/

but in order to get rid of the error you might want to try:

```
var str = {"Acc":"Hello_10" , "adm_data":"Denied"};
console.log(String(str.Acc).match(/[0-9]+/g));
```

or

```
var str = {"Acc":"Hello_10" , "adm_data":"Denied"};
console.log(str.Acc.toString().match(/[0-9]+/g));
```

To know the difference between the 2 options, check: [What's the difference between String(value) vs value.toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945202/whats-the-difference-between-stringvalue-vs-value-tostring)