# jQuery's conditional taking always first condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this conditional function in jQuery, in order to show an specific message with it's own style when required:

```
function msg(type, text) {
    if (type="success"){
        $('.messageDisplay').attr('class', 'messageDisplay messages success');
        $('.messages').text(text);
        $('.messages').stop( true, false ).fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(450);}
    else if (type="info"){
        $('.messageDisplay').attr('class', 'messageDisplay messages info');
        $('.messages').text(text);
        $('.messages').stop( true, false ).fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(450);}
    else if (type="error"){
        $('.messageDisplay').attr('class', 'messageDisplay messages error');
        $('.messages').text(text);
        $('.messages').stop( true, false ).fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(450);}
    else if (type="warning"){
        $('.messageDisplay').addClass('messages warning');
        $('.messages').text(text);
        $('.messages').stop( true, false ).fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(450);}}
```

When call it, it only takes first condition, as the class that is always added to the `messageDisplay` div is `'messageDisplay messages info'`. For example, on this case I am calling the `"error"` message type:

```
$('.tableContent').on('click', '.editIcon', function (e){
        if (editing==1){
            msg("error", "Acepta o anula la edición actual antes de editar otro registro");}
```

And even when it takes the right text, generates a `success` style message:

```
<div class="messageDisplay messages success">Acepta o anula la edición actual antes de editar otro registro</div>
```

After checking several times what could be causing this behaviour in jQuery, I am unable to find it and I'm almost sure no other jQuery's function is causing this. Is it something wrong on the conditional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (type="success"){
```

should be

```
if (type=="success"){
```

And so on for all

```
= means assignment not comparison
```

Comment: ARG! Thank you very much. I'll tick in 12 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (type.toString() === "success") {

.
```

or  if you're sure about `type` being a string then

```
if (type === "success")
```

And the same for all your conditions.

You're using `"="` operator, and that it's for assign, use `"==="` to be sure you're comparing same type (strings) besides the value.

At least you're 100% sure about "type" being a string better convert it with `toString()`

Also you could use `toString()` but there are some diff you may want to check, see this question for it:
[What's the difference between String(value) vs value.toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945202/whats-the-difference-between-stringvalue-vs-value-tostring)

**Note:** About `==` and `===` take a look to this question:
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: Thank you Allende. I was looking for the basic error (was using = instead of ==). Thanks for your attention.