# Typescript declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript, declaration

I'm currently learning Typescript declarations, but I'm stuck on the concept of passing a varying number of parameters to a function.

In other words, how do I make a Typescript declaration for a JavaScript function like this:

```
// Formats a string with the supplied parameter(s)
// Examples Usage: 
//  formatString("User {0} logged in", 'John');
//  formatString("Max {0} words allowed", 128.8999);
//  formatString("Form {0} to {1}", [10, 100]);

const function FormatString(sTemplate, params) {
    if (typeof params != undefined && arguments.length == 2) {
        if (params.constructor != Array) {
            if (typeof params == 'string')
                params = [params];
            else
                params = [String(params)];
        }

        if (params.constructor == Array) {
            $.each(params, function (index, value) {
                if (typeof value == 'string')
                    sTemplate = sTemplate.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + index + "\\}", "g"), value);
                else
                    sTemplate = sTemplate.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + index + "\\}", "g"), String(value));
            });
        }
    }
    return sTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Try to simplify example to a minimal problem

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL9XaW), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case. What is `$`? What is `const function`? Can you describe what you actually intend to accept as `params`?  Can it be anything at all?  Et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

1. In JavaScript/TypeScript, don't use `==` and `!=` when you want to mean strict equality or inequality; instead, do `===` and `!==`, otherwise the language [perfoms a looser comparison](https://howtodoinjava.com/javascript/javascript-equality-vs-identity-operators/) (e.g. `4 == '4'` is `true`, while `4 === '4'` is `false`).
2. To check if something is an `Array`, the more idiomatic solution is `Array.isArray(obj)`.
3. Try to avoid using `arguments`. It's considered bad practice and deprecated in practice, and some times not accessible at all. Using the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#the_difference_between_rest_parameters_and_the_arguments_object) parameter is usually better (safer, easier) to use.
4. To convert `number` to `string`, prefer the `.toString()` method, which ensures that it's actually a proper value and [errors when empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945202/whats-the-difference-between-stringvalue-vs-value-tostring).
5. No need to use `$` or any fancy dependency for something like `each()`; `array.forEach()` should be well supported in browsers by now.

With all of that said, an *opinionated* rewrite of your code would be:

```
const formatString = (sTemplate: string, ...params: Array<string | number>) => {
    params.forEach((value, index) => {
        const newValue = typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.toString(10);
        sTemplate = sTemplate.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + index + "\\}", "g"), newValue);
    });
    return sTemplate;
};

formatString("User {0} logged in", 'John');
formatString("Max {0} words allowed", 128.8999);
formatString("Form {0} to {1}", 10, 100);
```

Notice additional `params` being allowed, rather than an array. While you *can* achieve what you have in your message (either a single param, or an array of params), I think it would be a bit non-idiomatic and likely to cause confusion.

In my above case, you can *still* pass an array as a parameter (if, say, it's generated somewhere else) by using an array spread like so:

```
const nums = [10, 100];
formatString("Form {0} to {1}", ...nums);
```

If you want to keep your original syntax, however, you can use it like this:

```
const formatString = (sTemplate: string, params?: Array<string | number> | string | number) => {
    if (params !== undefined) {
        const newParams = Array.isArray(params) ? params : [params];
        newParams.forEach((value, index) => {
            const newValue = typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.toString(10);
            sTemplate = sTemplate.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + index + "\\}", "g"), newValue);
        });
    }
    return sTemplate;
};

formatString("User {0} logged in", 'John');
formatString("Max {0} words allowed", 128.8999);
formatString("Form {0} to {1}", [10, 100]);
formatString("No params");
```

But one additional caveat is that you can't use `undefined` as an actual parameter if if it's a single parameter; it'll assume it's not there and not perform the replacement in the template.

Good luck on your learning journey! JavaScript is a language that has some gotchas like the `==`/`!=` case mentioned above, but TypeScript certainly makes it easier to get to valid, safe code, so I would recommend staying in that path!