# Transform a number to string inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

Having the following input array:

```
  const input = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 3
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 4
    }
  ];
```

it must be changed to

```
  output = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: '1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: '2'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: '3'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: '4'
    }
  ];
```

so the value of name to be converted to string. I have found a method to do it but it seems like too complicated:

```
  const output = input.map((el) => ({
    ...el,
    name: el.name.toString()
  }));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: To cast numbers to strings in javascript there are several ways, your way is good but if you want a shorter way you can use `number  + ''` statement as in  `output = input.map(x=>({id:x.id,name:name+''}))`

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([{id:1,name:1},{id:2,name:2}]).replaceAll(/("name":)(\d+)/g,"$1\"$2\""))`, if you just want to see the world burn.

Answer (score 0):

Using destructuring and `String`.

Check the differences with `toString` and `String` here [What's the difference between String(value) vs value.toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945202/whats-the-difference-between-stringvalue-vs-value-tostring)

```js
const input = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 3,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 4,
  },
];

const output = input.map(({ name, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  name: String(name),
}));

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution you provided is perfectly fine and I don't think there is a better solution. Depending on whether you need to copy the array or not, you could use this solution, too:

```
input.forEach(el => el.name = el.name.toString());
```

This solution will modify the objects instead of creating new ones.

Comment: In the question the OP wants to create a new output object, you are modifying the original object ...

Comment: I am aware that I am modifying the original object(s), that is why I explicitly stated that in my answer.